# Are there any ma'amrei chazal on תּוֹלָע בֶּן-פּוּאָה?

Tags: sources-mekorot, historical-figures, shoftim--book-of

תּוֹלָע בֶּן-פּוּאָה was the shofet from Yissachar ([Shoftim 10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0710.htm):1-2). I have not been able to find any information on him anywhere. Do chazal or any later commentators mention anything about him?

Answer (score 3):

See [Seder Hadoros (2719)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=) for some information. He quotes [Gilgulie Neshamos](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA) by R' Menachem Azarya Mipano) that he was a gilgul of Binayhu ben Yehuyada who brought the Shamir worm to Shlomo Hamelech (see Gittin 58a); thus the name תולע (lit. worm), and his location being Shamir. There is a bit more discussion about him [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22685&pgnum=249), [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94), and on [wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94).

Answer (score 2):

R' Chaim Vital in *Sha'ar HaGilgulim* writes that Tola's soul was an incarnation of Haran's soul, as was Aharon HaKohen and Shmuel HaNavi ([*Hakdama* 36](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14180&st=&pgnum=108&hilite=)).

The Yalkut Shimoni notes that we can learn a lesson from the list of shoftim: all of the tribes except Shimon had a representative among the shoftim or kings. This was a consequence for the tribe's involvement in the debauchery at Pe'or (*Yalkut Shimoni*, *Shoftim*, 42).